# Issue with accounts

Tags: support, merge-accounts

It is really annoying that my account is getting sinked with others account. And I wander what is happening. Is there some bug. Because it is the second time my account has been deleted and my points being transferred to others account.

I once logged in to my stack account in one my my friends laptop and when he logged into his account my account got merged into his and all my details were updated with his. And this is not the first time.

Now what should I do?

I asked my friend and he also tried to logout but he can not logout. After signing from his account he is again redirected to my account.

This account belongs to Sachin Prasad:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2840147/sunil-singh
But it is merged with Sunil Singh.

And it is really annoying.

Just look at the account URL it has no question and answer but it has lot of points.

If you still doubt search my name on google 'sachin prasad' and you can see my stack link on first page.

Answer (score 5):

The last merge I see on this account happened over 6 months ago.

If you're logging into your account while your friend is still logged into his... On the same machine... In the same browser... They're very likely to be merged. The solution is to not do all of that.

If you use the "contact us" link at the bottom of this page and explain what's going on, we'll see what we can do to help you out.

Comment: The thing is I want my account back with my details and also the badges. Now tell me what I should do?

Comment: Your account is gone. Create a new account and contact us - we'll see what we can restore.